# POSIX -- what are intended use cases for termios members?

Tags: c, posix, termios

I am learning how to C program the terminals on Linux.

So in theory I open some pseudo terminal e.g. `/dev/pts/1` and in this pseudo terminal, I run a C program to which I pass an argument `/dev/ttyUSB1` in order for my C program to connect to the device that was assigned a device file `/dev/ttyUSB1` after it was connected to my Linux computer.

If I understand correctly I have to now properly set:

- `/dev/pts/1` ⟶ *"stdin" (how I localy input data)*
- `/dev/pts/1` ⟶ *"stdout" (how data is displayed on screen)*
- `/dev/ttyUSB1` ⟶ *"serial interface" (how data is sent and recieved)*.

---

C POSIX `termios` structure looks like this:

| member | explanation | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `c_cflag` | control options | Controls terminal's hardware. |
| `c_lflag` | local options | Controls various functions *(for local input)*. |
| `c_iflag` | input options | Controls basic terminal's input control *(for input driver buffer)*. |
| `c_oflag` | output options | Controls terminal's treatment of output *(for output driver buffer)*. |
| `c_cc` | Array with control characters | / |

Now to me it looks like not all the `termios` options are to be used in all scenarios. For example I suspect this:

- I suspect that `c_cflag` should only be used only for `/dev/ttyUSB1` and they make no sense if they are used for `/dev/pts/1` *("stdin" or "stdout")*.
- Same for `c_iflag`...
- Same for `c_oflag`...
- I also suspect that `c_lflag` should only be used only for `/dev/pts1` *("stdin" or "stdout")* and they make no sense if they are used for `/dev/ttyUSB1`.

---

**Question:**

Are my suspicions correct? Is there anything I should also keep in mind? I know that flags used with `open()` also greatly affect I/O functions...

Comment: These flags come in many forms. Some apply only to a physical communication layer, if present, others only make sense if you can read or write from the "file". Which flags are you the most concerned about making a mistake with?

Comment: @tadman So in my case I assume that `/dev/ttyUSB1` is a *"communication channel"* while `/dev/pts/1` is a *"terminal" (pseudo terminal actually)*...

Comment: @tadman I just wonder if there is any general rule where to use the flags.

Comment: That's a distinction that doesn't always matter. Both of them behave largely the same, it's just that setting baud rate on an internal pseudo-TTY doesn't really do anything, while on an RS232 it will change the behaviour.

Comment: These flags aren't something you'll use very often, if ever. Most of them are there to ensure completeness from an implementation perspective so if someone has to interface a 9600 baud VT100 over RS232 to their computer they can do it. These days that's kind of an unusual thing to do.

Comment: @tadman As you pointed out as well... It is true that `c_cflag` can't be used on a terminal, but is supposed to be used on a communication channels only.

Comment: "Terminal" is the thing that sends and receives data, usually with the intent to display. "Channel" is the way that terminal connects to your computer. "Virtual terminal" and "pseudo TTY" are software versions of the same things. Note that all of these terms used to mean physical things, like a port or a connector or a physical terminal device, but now they're more abstract concepts.

Comment: Thank you for some background. So, are my suspicions correct?

Comment: Roughly, sure, but if you had a specific situation or use-case in mind that'd help narrow down any confusion.

Comment: @KamilCuk but if you set a baudrate for a terminal, that does nothing... So how can you state that: *"All termios members should be used on all terminal devices."*?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for shortcuts, but that would be contrary to the portability goals of POSIX.  All fields of the termios structure should have sane values regardless of the actual "terminal" opened/used.  *"I also suspect that `c_lflag` ... make no sense if they are used for `/dev/ttyUSB1`"* -- Your suspicion is very incorrect.  A serial "port" is accessed as a serial terminal, and requires a full termios specification.

Comment: @sawdust Not the shortcut. Just some logic... *"Your suspicion is very incorrect. A serial "port" is accessed as a serial terminal, and requires a full termios specification."* I did test this myself and serial "communication channel" (`/dev/ttyUSB1`) was really acting strange until it's `c_lflag` flags weren't set to the **same** values as the `c_lflag` flags for stdin of the *"terminal"*   (`/dev/pts/1`).

Comment: *"I did test this myself ..."* -- Your improper *"test"* doesn't refute anything I wrote.  *"... really acting strange .."* - The adjective *"strange"* is not a technical term, and simply means you don't understand or know it.   *" it's [sic] `c_lflag` flags weren't set to the **same** values..."* -- Each type of terminal has its own default set of attributes and operational requiements.  Also you are probably not adhering to best practice, e.g. see [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).

Comment: ***"What's more, different terminal devices may require different mode settings in order to function properly. So you should avoid blindly copying attributes from one terminal device to another."***  from [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)

Comment: So there actually are no rules...

Comment: There are rules, but nothing like what you're trying to concoct.